# Editing the IDL created by OLE view for a C++ component

Tags: c++, idl

What things do I need to consider when doing this:

- What to **remove/manipulate/add**

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Defining interfaces in IDL for client neutrality**](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/ExtendingArcObjects/Appendices/EditingIDL.htm#Defining_interfaces_in_IDL_for_client_neutrality)

A number of issues are described in the **link** above to take note

Comment: Surely the author of the original type library took that into account.

Comment: That is what I thought, but no they didn't! Imagine... I'll attempt to contact them directly - regarding